# MySQL connector for Python throws "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm currently using a Mac and downloaded the MySQL connector a few weeks ago using pip. Got it working just fine with this exact same file that I'm trying to run now. Problem being, I'm getting this error now:

This is the code from the file:

```
import mysql.connector

mindatabase=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='Lagersjefen2020', passwd='lagerpassord', db='heltnydatabase')

settinn_markor=mindatabase.cursor()
markor=mindatabase.cursor()

settinn_markor.execute("INSERT INTO Vare"
                       "(VNr, Betegnelse, Pris, KatNr, Antall, Hylle)"
                       "VALUES('9999', 'Testvare', 99.99, 999, 99, 'T99')")

mindatabase.commit()

markor.execute('SELECT * FROM Vare')

for row in markor:
    print(row)

settinn_markor.close()
markor.close()

mindatabase.close()
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peterburkland/Desktop/tester1.py", line 8, in <module>
    settinn_markor.execute("INSERT INTO Vare"
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 598, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 354, in _send_cmd
    return self._socket.recv()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 267, in recv_plain
    raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2013)
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I've tried running other files as well getting a similar error, but with "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1044 (42000): Access denied for user" in the last line instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message closer:

```
GRANT ALL ON heltnydatabase.* TO Lagersjefen2020@localhost
```

Then your user can modify/read all the tables in this database.

Other finer granted options exist. Only needs to be executed once.